# Factory method to create object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two other class's one called product and another called promotion product, promotion product is an extension of product.class and in addition to the features of the product it can also have a prize inside. the object created in the promotion product class has a protected boolean prizeWinning that can be set to true or false. Now the product factory class describes an object which has a method makeProduct that can be called to return a new PromotionProduct object. The ProductFactory class should be set up so that a proportion of cans that are produced are prize-winning products, the proportion should be an argument to the ProductFactory constructor. Also i used Random class to make a random decision on whether a new PromotionProduct obj returned is a prize winning product.

I want to give ProductFactory a method which represents a switch – when you turn it one way, makeProduct returns ordinary product objects, when you turn 
it the other way, makeProduct returns PromotionProduct objects.

I am unsure of how to do this in this instance, could i use a switch method?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

class ProductFactory {

private ArrayList<PromotionProduct> prizeWinning, noPrize;
Random generator = new Random();
protected boolean randomGen = generator.nextBoolean();

public ProductFactory(int p, int a, String cont) {
    int proportion = p;
    int amount = a;
    prizeWinning = new ArrayList<PromotionProduct>();
    noPrize = new ArrayList<PromotionProduct>();
    prizeWinning.add(proportion, makesProduct(cont));
    for (int i = 0; i < proportion; i++) {
        prizeWinning.get(i).prizeWinning = true;
    }
    int left = amount - proportion;
    prizeWinning.add(left, makesProduct(cont));
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++) {
        noPrize.get(i).prizeWinning = false;
    }
}

public PromotionProduct makesProduct(String cont) {
    return new PromotionProduct(cont);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to differentiate on which object type you want to return based on what you pass in to makesProduct. You can also make that method static. I'll also assume that PromotionProduct is a subclass of Product. Something like:

```
public static Product makesProduct(String cont, Class<?> clazz) {
    if(clazz == Product.class) { 
        return new Product(cont);
    } else if (clazz == PromotionProduct.class) {
        return new PromotionProduct(cont);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type");
    }         
}
```

Comment: That's a good start. Now @fooll needs to go back in and implement the random generator/proportion. Also, you don't need two separate ArrayLists. Just use one ArrayList<Product> myList = new ArrayList<>();